# Searching listview items using Linq

Tags: wpf, linq, listview, binding

I have a listview bound to a collectionview of Entity objects (called Message)

The listview items binding refresh gets triggered when the Message objects collection changes (dispatchertimer).

When this happens the currently selected item in the listview is deselected.

How can I do a LINQ search on the listview items collection to find a message object of a certain id and reselect it?

```
int id = ((Message)lvMessages.SelectedItem).Id;

lvMessages.DataContext = service.Messages;
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvMessages.ItemsSource);
view.Filter = new Predicate<object>(FilterMessageItem);

//var li = lvMessages.Items.Cast<Message>().Where(m => m.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();

lvMessages.SelectedItem = li;
```

I'm not really sure how to set up the Linq query as I get this error on the commented line...

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'BusinessObjects.Message'. An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

Maybe there is a better way to populate the listview with changed items in the collection? not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "you don't".

If you've bound the Listview's `ItemSource` to a collection on the ViewModel, then create a property on the ViewModel for the selected item (Either a `DependencyProperty` or POCO with `INotifyPropertyChanged`) and bind the Listview's `SelectedItem` attribute to that property.

When you select an item in the Listview, this property value will be updated, and changing the value in the ViewModel using the property will update the selection in the Listview. Using MVVM and bindings there's really no need to access view controls etc. from the ViewModel or anywhere else, including code-behind.